# How can I disable keyword highlighting for lookup on Mac OS?

Tags: macos

Mac OS has started adding this annoying grey box around keywords/topics when I mouse over them. It happens a lot when I am typing about movie titles and other known hot topic items. If you click on the grey box it does a "Lookup" on the keyword.

How can I disable this auto highlighting of keywords for lookup?

[image]

Comment: In which apps is this occurring?

Comment: @drivec I have noticed it in Simplenote, Apple Notes, Tick Tick, ... It seems to be system wide when you are editing plain text.

Comment: In which macOS is this occurring?

Comment: @IconDaemon 10.13.2